# How to link an image to a string and call it when that string is called?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, random

I am working in JavaScript. I have two variable arrays. The first array consists of strings, the second array consists of images that correspond to each of those strings. My code calls a string from the first array at random, and now I want to link my image array such that the image associated with that randomly selected string is called as well. I figured out how to call an image from the second array at random, but I'm struggling to get it to align with the random selection of the string from the first array. I suspect this is a pretty simple fix, but I am very new to all this and any help is most appreciated!

Comment: why not have key value pairs in a object? `const obj = {label: 'cat', img: './assests/cat.jpg'}` can you post your code

Comment: Show us the basic code you have now as per [mcve]

Comment: Joe, to use your example, I am asking the user to guess a 3-letter word. All the user sees initially is _ _ _. No letters, and no image. Only after user guesses all three letters do I want the image of the cat to appear.

Comment: Working code snippets:                                                                  
var mySt = ["s1","s2"];
var myImgs = ["img_s1","img_s2"];                                                    
var selSt = "";                                                                   
function randString()   {
     selString = myStrings[Math.floor(Math.random() * myStrings.length)];
     letsinString = selString.split("");
     numBlanks = letsinString.length;                                          
function rndC() {if (letsinWord.toString() == yAndn.toString()) {w++;